# Fuzzy pattern search in a string: the most frequent patterns with d-mismatches

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I would like to find all patterns that are
1) the most frequent in a string
2) have at most d-mismatches.

For this given task, I have implemented function that counts for a given patter how many times it occurs in a string with d-mismatches. The idea of this algorithm is based on using convolution of a bit mask of a sub-pattern of a string and a bit mask of a given pattern. It produces the correct results. Here the code for this algorithm:

```
def create_bit_mask(letter, text):
buf_array=[]
for c in text:
    if c==letter:
        buf_array.append(1)
    else:
        buf_array.append(0)
return buf_array

def convolution(bit_mask1, bit_mask2):
return sum(b*q for b,q in zip(bit_mask1, bit_mask2))

def number_of_occurances_with_at_most_hamming_distance(genome,pattern,hamming_distance):
alphabet=["A","C","G","T"]
matches=0
matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_pattern=[]
matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_genome=[]
buf_output=0
buf=0
positions=""

for symbol in alphabet:
    matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_pattern.append(create_bit_mask(symbol,pattern))
    matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_genome.append(create_bit_mask(symbol, genome))

for i in xrange(len(genome)-len(pattern)+1):
    buf_debug=[]

    buf=sum(convolution(bit_mask_pattern,bit_mask_genome[i:i+len(pattern)]) for bit_mask_pattern, bit_mask_genome in zip(matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_pattern,matrix_of_bit_arrays_for_genome))
    hamming=len(pattern)-buf
    if hamming<=hamming_distance:
        buf_output+=1
        #print "current window: ", genome[i:i+len(pattern)], "pattern :", pattern,"number of mismatches : ", hamming, " @ position : ",i 

return buf_output
```

Given the function above, the solution for the task should be rather simple i.e.

```
def fuzzy_frequency():
genome="CACAGTAGGCGCCGGCACACACAGCCCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGCCCCGGGCCGGCGGCCGCCGGCGCCGGCACACCGGCACAGCCGTACCGGCACAGTAGTACCGGCCGGCCGGCACACCGGCACACCGGGTACACACCGGGGCGCACACACAGGCGGGCGCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGTACCGGGCCGCCGGCGGCCCACAGGCGCCGGCACAGTACCGGCACACACAGTAGCCCACACACAGGCGGGCGGTAGCCGGCGCACACACACACAGTAGGCGCACAGCCGCCCACACACACCGGCCGGCCGGCACAGGCGGGCGGGCGCACACACACCGGCACAGTAGTAGGCGGCCGGCGCACAGCC"
length=10
hamming_distance=2

for i in range(len(genome)-length):
    #print genome[i:i+10], " number of occurances: ", number_of_occurances_with_at_most_hamming_distance(genome, genome[i:i+10],hamming_distance)
    print (genome[i:i+length],number_of_occurances_with_at_most_hamming_distance(genome, genome[i:i+length],hamming_distance))
```

However, the code above doesn't find the following sub-string:

```
GCACACAGAC
```

Could you give me a hit, why? I don't want you to post the correct code, rather give me an idea, where is my mistake (I assume mistake might be in the second function).

P.S. I do realize that the following task I have to solve on Stepic on-line course, but given no feedback from that on-line society that is for the studying group, I have posted my code at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar genome parsing questions posed on the pyparsing list, and I came up with this CloseMatch parser class. It encapsulates much of your string walking and testing code within pyparsing's own string parsing framework, but this still might give you some insights into your own code:

```
genome = "CACAGTAGGCGCCGGCACACACAGCCCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGCCCCGGGCCGGCGGCCGCCGGCGCCGGCACACCGGCACAGCCGTACCGGCACAGTAGTACCGGCCGGCCGGCACACCGGCACACCGGGTACACACCGGGGCGCACACACAGGCGGGCGCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGTACCGGGCCGCCGGCGGCCCACAGGCGCCGGCACAGTACCGGCACACACAGTAGCCCACACACAGGCGGGCGGTAGCCGGCGCACACACACACAGTAGGCGCACAGCCGCCCACACACACCGGCCGGCCGGCACAGGCGGGCGGGCGCACACACACCGGCACAGTAGTAGGCGGCCGGCGCACAGCC"
length=10
hamming_distance=2

from pyparsing import Token, ParseException
# following from pyparsing.wikispaces.com Examples page
class CloseMatch(Token): 
    """A special subclass of Token that does *close* matches. For each
       close match of the given string, a tuple is returned giving the
       found close match, and a list of mismatch positions."""
    def __init__(self, seq, maxMismatches=1): 
        super(CloseMatch,self).__init__() 
        self.name = seq 
        self.sequence = seq 
        self.maxMismatches = maxMismatches 
        self.errmsg = "Expected " + self.sequence 
        self.mayIndexError = False 
        self.mayReturnEmpty = False 

    def parseImpl( self, instring, loc, doActions=True ): 
        start = loc 
        instrlen = len(instring) 
        maxloc = start + len(self.sequence) 

        if maxloc <= instrlen: 
            seq = self.sequence 
            seqloc = 0 
            mismatches = [] 
            throwException = False 
            done = False 
            while loc < maxloc and not done: 
                if instring[loc] != seq[seqloc]: 
                    mismatches.append(seqloc) 
                    if len(mismatches) > self.maxMismatches: 
                        throwException = True 
                        done = True 
                loc += 1 
                seqloc += 1 
        else: 
            throwException = True 

        if throwException: 
            #~ exc = self.myException 
            #~ exc.loc = loc 
            #~ exc.pstr = instring 
            #~ raise exc 
            raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg)

        return loc, (instring[start:loc],mismatches) 


# first walk genome, get all unique N-character patterns
patterns = set()
for i in range(len(genome)-length):
    patterns.add(genome[i:i+length])
print len(patterns)

# use pyparsing's CloseMatch to find close matches - each match
# returns the substring and the list of mismatch locations
matches = {}
for p in sorted(patterns):
    matcher = CloseMatch(p, hamming_distance)
    matches[p] = list(matcher.scanString(genome, overlap=True))

# Now list out all patterns and number of close matches - for the most
# commonly matched pattern, dump out all matches, where they occurred and
# an annotated match showing the mismatch locations
first = True
for p in sorted(matches, key=lambda m: -len(matches[m])):
    if first:
        first = False
        for matchdata in matches[p]:
            matchvalue, start, end = matchdata
            substring,mismatches = matchvalue[0]
            print ' ', substring, 'at', start
            if mismatches:
                print ' ', ''.join('^' if i in mismatches else ' ' for i in range(length))
            else:
                print ' ', "***EXACT***"
            print
    print p, len(matches[p])
```

There are 254 unique 10-character patterns in the given genome.

Here is the output for the most commonly matched pattern:

```
  CGGCACACAC at 12
  ^^        

  GCACACACAG at 14
    ^      ^

  GGGTACACAC at 126
   ^ ^      

  GGGCGCACAC at 138
   ^  ^     

  GCGCACACAC at 140
  ***EXACT***

  GCACACACAG at 142
    ^      ^

  CGGCACACAC at 213
  ^^        

  GCACACACAG at 215
    ^      ^

  GCCCACACAC at 227
    ^       

  GCGCACACAC at 253
  ***EXACT***

  GCACACACAC at 255
    ^       

  ACACACACAC at 257
  ^ ^       

  GCGCACAGCC at 272
         ^^ 

  CCGCCCACAC at 280
  ^   ^     

  GCCCACACAC at 282
    ^       

  CCACACACAC at 284
  ^ ^       

  GGGCGCACAC at 316
   ^  ^     

  GCGCACACAC at 318
  ***EXACT***

  GCACACACAC at 320
    ^       

  GCGCACAGCC at 351
         ^^
```

Comment: Do I correctly understand that the most frequent pattern with 2 mismatches is `GCGCACACAC`? If yes, then my program and yours give the same results that is might be a sign that our solutions are correct.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. Even if the pyparsing code is not directly applicable or accessible to you, you might be able to crib from my output code, showing the mismatch markers under the matched substrings. And as you say, it's encouraging when a different approach altogether yields the same result - bolsters your confidence that your answer might actually be correct.

Comment: There is one "bug" in this code, in that it only dumps out the first from a list of patterns sorted in descending order of matches. If there are two patterns tied for the greatest number of matches, this will only show the first one, and there is no guarantee which will be "first".

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

Aaaaand, here is an re-based solution:

```
genome = "CACAGTAGGCGCCGGCACACACAGCCCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGCCCCGGGCCGGCGGCCGCCGGCGCCGGCACACCGGCACAGCCGTACCGGCACAGTAGTACCGGCCGGCCGGCACACCGGCACACCGGGTACACACCGGGGCGCACACACAGGCGGGCGCCGGGCCCCGGGCCGTACCGGGCCGCCGGCGGCCCACAGGCGCCGGCACAGTACCGGCACACACAGTAGCCCACACACAGGCGGGCGGTAGCCGGCGCACACACACACAGTAGGCGCACAGCCGCCCACACACACCGGCCGGCCGGCACAGGCGGGCGGGCGCACACACACCGGCACAGTAGTAGGCGGCCGGCGCACAGCC"
length=10
hamming_distance=2


import re
from itertools import product

charset = "ACGT"

# first walk genome, get all unique N-character patterns
patterns = set()
for i in range(len(genome)-length):
    patterns.add(genome[i:i+length])


# for each pattern, create re's with all possible alternates
allmatches = {}
for p in sorted(patterns):
    options = [[c,"["+charset+"]"] for c in p]
    proditer = product(*options)

    matches = set()
    for pr in proditer:
        # count how many elements in this product start with '['
        # only want up to hamming_distance number of alternatives
        numalts = sum(prpart.startswith('[') for prpart in pr)
        if numalts > hamming_distance:
            continue

        compiled_pattRE = re.compile(''.join(pr))
        for match in filter(None, (compiled_pattRE.match(genome,i) 
                                        for i in range(len(genome)-length+1))):
            matches.add((match.start(), match.group(0)))

    allmatches[p] = matches

for p,matches in sorted(allmatches.items(), key=lambda m: -len(m[1])):
    print p, len(matches)
    for m in sorted(matches):
        print m
    print
    break
```

prints:

```
GCGCACACAC 20
(12, 'CGGCACACAC')
(14, 'GCACACACAG')
(126, 'GGGTACACAC')
(138, 'GGGCGCACAC')
(140, 'GCGCACACAC')
(142, 'GCACACACAG')
(213, 'CGGCACACAC')
(215, 'GCACACACAG')
(227, 'GCCCACACAC')
(253, 'GCGCACACAC')
(255, 'GCACACACAC')
(257, 'ACACACACAC')
(272, 'GCGCACAGCC')
(280, 'CCGCCCACAC')
(282, 'GCCCACACAC')
(284, 'CCACACACAC')
(316, 'GGGCGCACAC')
(318, 'GCGCACACAC')
(320, 'GCACACACAC')
(351, 'GCGCACAGCC')
```

Comment: Well, I bet that there is the following conceptual mistake (not in your and my code). The sub-pattern that I am looking for (with d-mismatches) is might not be in a genome. Thus slicing given genome into the sub-patterns and for a given sub-pattern perform "fuzzy" counting might give the less results then comparing to the following approach: a) generate the set of all strings with given length based on a given alphabet b) from each string form the set above perform fuzzy counting with d-mismatches.

Comment: Ah, good point! I'll amend to generate the 4**10 combinations and see if any of them have more hits than any of those 10-character strings that are sliced from the genome. (There's probably a mathematical proof that there can or can't be such a solution.)

Comment: Well, if you implement brute force solution it will be really time consuming. I am struggling to find more efficient algo to implement this idea.

Comment: Ha! It *can* happen! I implemented a brute force solution and changed your length to 6, and the most common match with up to 2 errors is "CCCGCC", which does not exist anywhere in the genome.

Comment: How did you generate all strings with a given length on a given alphabet? I am using the following code to do this: `alphabet=["A","C","G","T"] buf_results = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat = length)]`

Comment: Pretty much as you did: `patterns = [''.join(pr) for pr in product("ACGT", repeat=length)]`. Then at the end, for each matched string `p`, I print out `"NY"[p in genome]`, which will print out "Y" or "N" if p is or is not a substring of the genome.

Comment: Ok, my program is still working))) I am implementing this algorithm on macbook air, 2GB RAM, Intel Core i5. I don't grasp the idea how to satisfy the 5 minute time constraint.

Comment: My pyparsing solution is surprisingly about 3-4 times faster than the re solution.